# Shared variable read from low priority thread in preemptive scheduling

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, mutex, critical-section

Single core embedded system

Priority based scheduling

Thread 2(T2) - High priority

Thread 1(T1) - Low priority

Single producer(T2) and single consumer (T1)

**Requirement:**

1. Data flow from T2 to T1 through shared circular buffer. Data flow
   possible in one direction i.e. T2 to T1.
2. Between threads planning to use circular buffer as shared memory to
   post received packets from T2 to T1.
3. T2 will enqueue and T1 will dequeue the packets from circular buffer.
4. And planning to add enqueue index and dequeue index pointer for circular buffer as volatile(consider it won't solve critical section problem).
5. T2 will update the Enqueue index pointer in circular buffer and T2
   will update the Dequeue index pointer in circular buffer.
6. T1 thread will check Enqueue and dequeue index are equal before
   start to dequeue the packet from circular buffer.

**Query:**

- while T1 thread(low priority) trying to read the enqueue index, let's say in
  that instance task switched to high priority thread T2 and it will update the  enqueue index variable?
- In this case again task switched to T1, whether variable 'enqueue index' read will give old value or INVALID value?
- My understanding is, for my requirement T2->T1 direction only
  possible so here critical section issue will not come in preemptive
  scheduling

Please give your views

Comment: Producer has higher priority than the consumer? There _could_ be a valid reason for that in your specific application, but in the _general_ case, it's a Bad Idea. In software, as in real-life, you normally want to prioritize _finishing_ jobs over starting new jobs. Give priority to threads or processes that release resources and make space available over threads and processes that tie up resources.

Comment: (a) You should rewrite the question to use complete and grammatically correct sentences. While it is often possible to puzzle out your intention when verbs or other things are omitted, it is sometimes ambiguous and often leaves the reader unsure. (b) Whether T1 reading the enqueue index will get an invalid value or not when there are no locks depends on whether the index is atomic or not, which you have not specified in your question.

Comment: (c) Given what you have stated, it is possible T1 will read an old value. Maybe that does not happen because of characteristics of your system. But consider what happens if T1 reads the index and, immediately after that, before T1 can compare and branch based on that, T2 runs and changes the index. Even if the hardware and OS guarantee instant visibility of that change to T1, it is too late; T1 has already loaded an old value and is about to work with it. What happens then, does T1 go to sleep and not check again until woken? Will that wake occur? You have not provided details about that.

Comment: for your query (b): enqueue index will be declared as volatile pointer. There is no locking mechanics planned during read/write of enqueue index.

Comment: @codeflow: Volatile and atomic are not the same thing. Objects can be volatile but not atomic and can be atomic but not volatile.

Answer (score -1):

In standard C (and you don't specify an embedded dialect), reading an "enqueue index" or any other shared variable does not force thread scheduling. Hence, thread T1 probably continues to run. It reads the *last* value written by T2. If there is *no* value written yet, that's the regular C reading of uninitialized memory, i.e. Undefined Behavior. (Not "INVALID value")

I've got no idea why you mention a "critical section issue".